# Stuck on 'Enable delegation of user credentials' Windows Server Hyper-v 2012 r2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, credentials

Im trying to setup a Windows Server Hyper-V 2012 r2 server which I've installed, but am having issues connecting to it throught the Hyper-V manager on Windows 10. I have followed various instructions about WinRM and CredSSP however I still have the following issue. I launch the hyper-v manager and click 'Connect to server'. I put in the ip address and set the username and password for the hyper-v server. When I click 'Ok' however, I get an error saying 'This computer is not configured to allow delegation of user credentials'. If I click 'Yes' to suposedly allow it to delegate the credentials, the message pops up again. If I click no I get another error saying 'Could not connect to the Virtual Machine Management' and 'A computer policy does not allow the delegations of the user credentials to the target computer'. I can access and control it fine with the Server Manager. Any thoughts?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDTI6.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Is the Hyper-V server along with Management host joined to the domain? In the case it's not please see the following link - [Remote connect to HyperV Host machine from Windows 10 Console](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/14c1cb56-c99d-4910-ad17-ec13117e090f/remote-connect-to-hyperv-host-machine-from-windows-10-console?forum=winserverhyperv).

Where steps with enabling and configuring WinRM described. Alternatively, you can either:

1. Disable the firewall
2. Configure local group policies as described in link above

Comment: I'll certainly have a look through this and try some of the suggestions. I'll let you know how it goes! Thanks for your input

Comment: Ok - I've looked through that thread and the tip about using the hostname not the IP address has got me a bit further. When I try and connect, the error about credentials is gone but now I get 'This version of hyper-v manager cannot be used to manage servers running 2012'. I am trying to use a windows server 2016 machine to manage it. Is there an issue there?